# Android: Refreshing GridView by Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, gridview, refresh

I have been facing a lot of difficulty over refreshing my GridView.

**Background of my Application:**
It is an application which gathers information from a router. This router actually gathers power information from all the various appliances connected to it. Let me get to the point here: on one of my android fragments, I am getting all the devices connected to the router and adding them to my GridView using an AsyncTask. This AsyncTask calls a PHP which outputs a JSON Array of all the devices. Then, I refresh this AsyncTask every 7 seconds, using a thread. In this thread, I first check if the Adapter is Empty, if it is not, I clear the Adapter, then I do a notifyDataSetChanged(); , then I set the adapter back to the grid. But what I get by doing this is after every 7 seconds, the GridView is appended with more information instead. The GridView does refresh, but another set of the same data is displayed on my GridView, with the old data, and as this is repeated, more and more contents get added to my GridView. I just wanted to clear the current data, then do a simple refresh every 7 seconds.

Here is my code:

**The Thread which refreshes AsyncTask(which displays the gridview) every 7 seconds:**

```
asyncThread =  new Thread(new Runnable(){
              @Override
                public void run() {

                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(7000);
                            refresher.post(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() { 

                                    Log.v("Grid Adapter is Empty",""+adapter.isEmpty());
                                    Log.v("Items ArrayList is  Empty", ""+items.isEmpty());
                                    if(!adapter.isEmpty() && !items.isEmpty())
                                    {

                                        adapter.clear();
                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        startNewAsyncTask();

                                    }

                                    else{
                                    startNewAsyncTask();
                                    }

                                }      
                            });
                        }
                        catch(InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }});
               asyncThread.start();
```

**Here is my AsyncTask(I have initialized the GridView and the Adapter above in my onCreateView() method):**

```
//Async Task to get the GridView which contains the individual devices
private  class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private WeakReference<LiveDataFragmentTemp> fragmentWeakRef;

    private MyAsyncTask (LiveDataFragmentTemp liveDataFragmentTemp) {
        this.fragmentWeakRef = new WeakReference<LiveDataFragmentTemp>(liveDataFragmentTemp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog= new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setMessage("Refreshing");
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

        dialog.setCancelable(false);        
        dialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // HTTP Client that supports streaming uploads and downloads
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());

        // Define that I want to use the POST method to grab data from
        // the provided URL
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(devicesData);

        //Define format of data being pulled
        httpget.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        // Used to read data from the URL
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        // Will hold the whole all the data gathered from the URL
        String result = null;

        try {

            // Get a response if any from the web service
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);        

            // The content from the requested URL along with headers, etc.
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            //Log.v("Entity", entity.toString());

            // Get the main content from the URL
            inputStream = entity.getContent();

            // JSON is UTF-8 by default
            // BufferedReader reads data from the InputStream until the Buffer is full
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);

            // Will store the data
            StringBuilder theStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;

            // Read in the data from the Buffer until nothing is left
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {

                // Add data from the buffer to the StringBuilder
                theStringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }

            // Store the complete data in result
            result = theStringBuilder.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {

            // Close the InputStream when you're done with it
            try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}
            catch(Exception e){}
        }

        // Holds Key Value pairs from a JSON source
        JSONObject jsonObject;
        try {

            //Store result in JSONObject
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            totalDevices = jsonObject.getInt("totalDevices");


            //Get JSONArray called "details"
            JSONArray deviceArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("details"); 

            for(int i=0;i<deviceArray.length();i++){

            //Get every JSON Object in array    
            JSONObject numJSONObject = deviceArray.getJSONObject(i); 

            //put Json Objects into new Array
            newArray.put(numJSONObject); 
            }

            }
             catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return result;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (this.fragmentWeakRef.get() != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject resultobj = new JSONObject(result);
                totalDevices = resultobj.getInt("totalDevices");



            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(totalDevices<=0)
            {

                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle("No Devices Connected!")
                .setMessage("Please make sure the router is online")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 

                    }
                 })

                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_alert)
                 .show();
            }
            else{
            //Take out all JSON Objects and extract the strings here
            for(int i=0;i<newArray.length();i++)
            {
                                    try {

                                                JSONObject newObj;
                                                newObj = newArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                                String deviceId = newObj.getString("deviceid");
                                                String deviceName = newObj.getString("device");
                                                String deviceState = newObj.getString("state");
                                                String activePower = newObj.getString("power");



                                                map = new HashMap<String, String>(); //Add all device details to HashMap

                                                    map.put(TAG_NAME, ""+deviceName);
                                                    map.put(TAG_STATE, ""+deviceState);
                                                    map.put(TAG_POWER, ""+activePower);
                                                    map.put(TAG_ID, ""+deviceId);


                                                    items.add(map); //put Hashmap into ArrayList



                                                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                   grid.setAdapter(adapter); //set Adapter to GridView

                                                   dialog.dismiss();
                                                //OnClick Listener for GridView
                                                 grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                                                int position, long id) {

                                                            LiveDataFragmentTemp.devId = items.get(+position).get("deviceId");
                                                            Intent devDetails=new Intent(getActivity(), DeviceActivity.class);
                                                             //Transfer 3 details to DeviceActivity 
                                                            devDetails.putExtra("DEVICE ID", items.get(+position).get("deviceId"));
                                                            devDetails.putExtra("DEVICE NAME", items.get(+position).get("deviceName"));
                                                            devDetails.putExtra("DEVICE STATE", items.get(+position).get("state"));

                                                            startActivity(devDetails);
                                                            //Finish activity to stop all threads to reduce bandwidth usage
                                                            getActivity().finish(); 

                                                            return;
                                                        }});


                                    } catch (Exception e) {

                                        System.out.print(e);
                                    }
                                }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

**I start this AsyncTask by doing this method, which is called in my refresher thread above:**

```
//Method to start Async Task
    private void startNewAsyncTask() {
        MyAsyncTask asyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(this);
        this.asyncTaskWeakRef = new WeakReference<MyAsyncTask >(asyncTask); 
        asyncTask.execute();
    }
```

**Here is how I initialized my GridView and the CustomGridViewAdapter:**

```
grid=(GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView2); //initialize GridView
adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.main_custom, items); //Define each view using an Adapter
```

I have tried many things like clearing the hashmap, clearing the arraylist and also clearing the adapter, but none of them work. My gridview always keeps refreshing with more and more items.

Your help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**PS: If you are thinking why I used "CustomListViewAdapter", it's because I was previously working on a ListView and I just used the same class for my GridView. Sorry for any inconvenience.**

Comment: why are you using a Thread to start an AsyncTask?

Comment: @blackbelt how else can I go about doing it? I did it because I need to refresh the whole task every seven seconds, filling the grid view up in the process.